# Why I am getting error invalid hook call when I am calling it inside a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a function that is called over multiple  components and I wanted to put it in a helpers file like this:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { quoteActions } from "../../_actions";
export const nextScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(quoteActions.nextStep());
  dispatch(quoteActions.disableContinue(true));
};
```

Then when I go within a component where I have to use that function:

```
import {nextScreen} from '../helpers/';
function Screen1(props){
 useEffect(()=>{
   props.ref.current.addEventListener("click",nextScreen);
   return ()=> props.ref.current.removeEventListener("click",nextScreen);
},[])
 return(
  ...
)
}
```

if I declare nextScreen inside Screen1 component it works but not if I put it in a separate file, why?
I tried importing React in the file I declared nextScreen but it didn't fix it, also tried returning null

Comment: you need to add `useDispatch` hook in the root of the folder

Answer (score 1):

Functions that use hooks (like `useDispatch`) are called [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook), you need to add the `use` prefix to help the linter check for [Rules Of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) violations.

```
export const useNextScreen = () => { ... };
```

Aside from the error, this code won't work as you must call hooks on the top level, the logic should be:

```
import { nextScreen } from "../helpers/";
function Screen1(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const nextScreen = () => {
      dispatch(quoteActions.nextStep());
      dispatch(quoteActions.disableContinue(true));
    };
    props.ref.current.addEventListener("click", nextScreen);
    return () => props.ref.current.removeEventListener("click", nextScreen);
  }, [dispatch]);
  return <></>;
}
```